GaN driver losses calculations
This is one of the first times I have looked at a datasheet, and I would like to get an estimate of the power dissipated during gate driver switching.
I've assumed some random data (hopefully realistic) and, if I'm not wrong, in line with the absolute max ratings of the driver in question. I also realize that for example Qg in the datasheet is specified for Vds=40V, while I assumed 50V, so "it would not fit."
I used a general formula that should included all losses:

Are the calculations correct?
Am I doing something wrong?
I repeat that the data are made up, so (given my inexperience) they might be unrealistic and strange!
I am interested if the gate driver parameters taken from the datasheet (Qg and Coss) are correct and if I have forgotten/made mistake something.
Thanks!!
(P.S.: in the datasheet there is the section "8.2.2.4 Power Dissipation" that shows the formula for calculating P_diss (as I did in the photo), but it seems to me to be lacking some terms ... or maybe it is neglected. I would like to compare the dissipation losses of multiple gate drivers with each other, so I would like to use one general formula including all the terms without having to check the single P_diss in each datasheet)

19W is definitely too much driver loss for a 500W supply.
Check your math.
For example, 0.5 * 266pF * 50V * 50V =/= 332mJ, more like 332nJ. That's the beauty of GaN (which i have 0 experience with), on a traditional mosfet this would be >10x higher.
check your math and SI prefixes, then come back again with a comment.
I know that is not your only issue with the numbers, but it is a glaring one and confuses from the rest of the question.
It would also help if you finished the math broke it out into the individual losses rather than the total loss.   I think your switching losses are overstated -- where did you find that expression?

In the calculations in the picture I wrote 332nJ (maybe my "n" looks like an "m"). The formula was given to me in college and I had found it in a tecnical document from st some time ago

Gate drive current is: \$ I_g = f \;Q_g \$.
Total gate charge, \$Q_g\$, for each GaN device is 15.8 nC.
Thus, the gate drive current is \$ 2 * 100e3 * 15.8e-9 = 3.2 \; mA \$.
The factor of two is for the two GaN FETs per package (high and low-side FETs). Power to drive gates is \$5 * 3.2 \;mA = 16 \; mW\$.
To calculate the output switching losses depends on the load and various currents, both real and reactive. This is a good job for a SPICE simulator.

Thank you for the comment. I am beginning to believe that the formula I wrote in the picture is valid "only" for single transistors, whereas in the case of a gate driver you have to refer exclusively to the formula given at the bottom of the datasheet. I mean, if the datasheet states the formula ... then I definitely use that.

@KaleM The formula given is in lots of literature. There will be additional losses in the driver circuitry which is hidden. It's best to go off of the $I_{CCO}$ specification on page 6 for VCC power consumption.

Still consider the LMG5200 (datasheet linked in the main post), isn't it better to use the formula in the datasheet in "9.2.2.3 Power Dissipation" rather than the formulas I wrote in my calculations? By the way they don't look the same to me, they have some similarities

@KaleM The power dissipation section gives information on switching losses for the output transistors which should be understood. Most of the heat will come from the output transistors if you are dealing with significant current. You are better off doing a SPICE simulation of the output stage if you have a complex load.
